# Is there a easier way to format this string?

Tags: c#

I've been attempting to format this string for a text box as it's getting typed in. The output result that I would like is as follows:

*user presses '0'*: output:'0 /  /    '

*user presses '6'*: output:'06/  /    '

*user presses '2'*: output:'06/2 /    '

etc.

What I currently have:

```cs
private void fTranDate_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && fTranDate.Text.Length > 10)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //Is numeric
    {
        //Get the string from the field
        var existing_string = fTranDate.Text;
        //Strip the spaces and the slashes from the string
        existing_string = existing_string.Replace("/", "").Replace(" ","");
        //Append the new digit to the end of the string
        existing_string= existing_string + e.KeyChar;
        //Re-add the spaces on the end of the string
        existing_string = String.Format("{0,-8}", existing_string);

        var existing_char = existing_string.ToCharArray();
        fTranDate.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}{3}/{4}{5}{6}{7}", existing_char[0],existing_char[1],existing_char[2],existing_char[3],existing_char[4],existing_char[5],existing_char[6],existing_char[7]);
        fTranDate.SelectionStart = fTranDate.Text.Replace(" ","").Length;
        fTranDate.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this more streamlined? I've tried some other ideas but this is the only one that works.

Comment: Take a look at [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=net-5.0).

Comment: ...or better, a [`DateTimePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=net-5.0). You may either set its `Format` property to `Short` or set it to `Custom` and use a custom format. You may also set `ShowUpDown` to true if you don't want the user to select from the calender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MaskedTextbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox) with the input mask `00/00/0000`.

**Edit** you can also set the `ValidatingType` property to `DateTime` type.

[image]

Comment: A nice example (on usage) is give here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.validatingtype?view=net-5.0